# Graphic Issues (Minecraft & Tekkit)

Tags: graphics, java, minecraft

I am running OpenJDK 7, though I have to launch .jar files with the terminal because it doesn't show up on the 'run with' menu. I am experiencing graphic/texture issues when running [Tekkit Classic](http://www.technicpack.net/modpack/tekkit.552560) and my screen flashes with white or black briefly, though often, and in different places. This also applies when I play vanilla [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/).
Sometimes the textures on chests, entities and players scramble leaving odd textures. (I would post images but I lack the *reputation* to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is "flashing", you can attempt pressing F11 which enables full-screen mode which solved the flashing for me, or try resizing the window almost the amount of full screen. If this doesn't fix it, the problem might be in your graphics card or drivers.